# How to make psql to default to localhost?

Tags: postgresql, 12.04

I have the following scenario:

```
saji@geeklap:~$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

saji@geeklap:~$ psql -h localhost -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (8.4.14)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I'm trying to log into the `postgresql` server installed in my system as user `postgres`. I'm able to login only if I specify `-h localhost`. Whereas `psql` documentation says that:

> If you omit the host name, psql will connect via a Unix-domain socket
>   to a server on the local host, or via TCP/IP to localhost on machines
>   that don't have Unix-domain sockets.

**Ref:** http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CON

Why am I unable to login without specifying the host, is there some configuration file that needs any change for things to occur as told in the `psql` documentation?

Comment: Create a `.psqlrc` that specifies the defaults - or just edit `pg_hba.conf` to use `md5` authentication for `local` (unix socket) connections. See the documentation for `pg_hba.conf` and `psql`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, it works as documented.

When the host name is omitted, `psql` connects to the Unix-domain socket whose path is compiled in. That part works in your case, otherwise it would output a different error message than what the question shows.

The error message in the question:

> ```
> psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
> ```

relates to the fact that only the Unix user postgres has the permission to connect as the database user postgres when using a Unix-domain socket. This is configured in the `pg_hba.conf` file.

what you should typically do in Ubuntu when you're logged in as a normal user, but you're the administrator of the system:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
```

Comment: Thanks.. Please change `sudo -u postgresql psql` to `sudo -u postgres psql`. I tried to edit. But couldn't, as the edit has only <6 characters.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't like the default of connecting via a unix socket, you can set the environment variable `PGHOST`. I have

```
export PGHOST="db"
```

in my `~/.bashrc`, to connect to the server with that name. A few more handy environment variables are documented at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-envars.html